# Getting the following error in R: Error: 1: Start tag expected, '<' not found

Tags: r

I searched the site thoroughly but didn't find an answer. The script looks into a file directory and appends into a vector of filenames (which I then turn into a dataframe). For is then used to iterate through custom function which consumes as argument the file name. The parser works fine with one file name (i.e. when I force it in `parser(filename)` otherwise fails when runs through the for loop). So I suspect it's how I'm passing the argument.

```
files <- list.files(path="~/pathname", pattern="*.xml", full.names = F, recursive=FALSE)
files.df <- as.data.frame(files)
for (i in 1:nrow(files.df)) {
parser(as.character(files.df[i,]))
}
```

When I `print(as.character(files.df[i,])`, the output is as expected. Again, running the custom parser with one file name (outside the for loop) as argument works perfectly. The `setwd` is the same as that of where the files are read from.

Anything you may have come across before?

*Update:* the script worked fine yesterday with one file but now I get the same error. It seems to happen at this line:

```
xmlfile=xmlParse(filename, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
```

Comment: As you said the error seems to be caused by `xmlParse()` and not the directory listing. I suspect there's one file in your folder that may contain invalid XML, maybe just an empty line at the start instead of the usual `<xml>` stuff. Doing a `print(filename)` before calling the XML parser will hopefully help you find the broken one

Comment: Thank you Chrki, I do not think it's the xml that's wrong as I was able to parse it last night. The xml file starts with: <?xml version="1.0"?> which is typical for xml files.

Comment: Can you add the first few lines of the XML?

Comment: Realised in the function I was overriding the xml file with the output and of course it worked the first time around as the xml was tact. The second time the xml was overriden with the result data. Appreciate your help here.

Comment: Alright, glad you figured it out!